# How can my app request sudo permissions when installed from the Software Center?

Tags: usb, permissions, udev

I have written a USB over IP server for Ubuntu and want to deploy it via the Ubuntu Software Center

However for the app to run, it requires sudo access to udev files.  Is there anyway to get sudo access through the Software Center for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also searching for an answer, although i think it isn't possible exactly through software centre.
It's probably some configuration in a setup.xx file.